# .should_receive understanding

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I've been following rspec book to learn more about cucumber and rpsec. But what I don't really understand is these lines below with comment :

```
messenger = mock("messenger").as_null_object
game.start(%w[a b c d])
messenger.should_receive(:puts).with("bbbb") # 1st line
game.guess(%w[a b c d]) # 2nd line

module Game
  #...
  def guess(guess)
    @messenger.puts "bbbb"
  end
end
```

My question is: I expected the 1 linw should be the 2nd and reverse, like we say it "the game start, if you guess this then you should receive this" but it doesn't work like that.

1. How does the should_receive work ?
2. Is it an observer which waits
       there and catch what stdout pops out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.should_receive` looks for a call after the all the statements have been executed.